# Image Scaling when using CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I have this UIImageview, with an image. It's a small image, that is tiled with the

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets
```

method. It's very useful to do screen size independent images, and it works well: if I programmatically change the frame size of the UIImageview, the image inside is not stretched, but repeated, so the pixels remain pixels.

Now, when I do a

```
self.myImageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(5.0, 5.0);
```

to the UIImageview containing/displaying that image, I notice that the image now actually is stretched.

I tried reloading the image into the view, but that doesn't seem to help.

The UIImageView is in the "Scale to Fill" mode.

The question in short is: how do I make sure the image is not stretched, but tiled after the transformation?

UPDATE: the reason for using CGAffineTransformMakeScale is, that I want to grow/shrink the image(view) relative to its center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the transform direct to the view, use `CGRectApplyAffineTransform` and transform the image view frame. This won't work well for all possible transformations though so limit to translation and scale.

Comment: That works fine, but the reason why I used CGAffineTransformMakeScale in the first place, was to do a scaling from the center: growing/shrinking the image(view), while keeping the center of the view pinned. I will edit my original question.

Comment: In that case your best option may be simply to use CGRectInset.